# User login based on SOAP service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

### Problem

I am working on creating a user application which I am connecting to a service via their SOAP API service; I have been able to get that working, and I get the desired response okay; but I am now facing a security concern when making the application login framework...

I would love to create my own code; but something Laravel would also work, for secure a development environment, which already the user login system, but I am not sure how I could go about connecting the service to the SOAP instance, instead of MySQL database, which is what I currently use.

Should I create a user on MySQL database based on the SOAP response? Or is there some way to create the instance based on the response from the service without having to continually remake the call?

### Response

These are the responses I receive from the service based.

This is what I receive back from it - GIVEN THAT the user login information is CORRECT:

```
Array(
    ['columnList'] => Array(
        [0] => 'Column1',
        [1] => 'Column2',
        [2] => 'Column3',
        [3] => 'Column4',
        [4] => 'Column5'
        // ... etc
    ),
    ['data'] => array(
        [0] => array(
            [0] => 'Value_1',
            [1] => 'Value_2',
            [2] => 'Value_3',
            [3] => 'Value_4',
            [4] => 'Value_5'
            // ... etc
        ),
        // if the user has more entries then we it will create more arrays below
    )
);
```

If the user's info is wrong or the user does not match I just get a string response

```
[string] 'nomatch'
```

### Attempt

I have attempted creating `$_SESSION` variables from the response I receive from the service:

The function `user_print` is my attempt to make a unique finger print for that user which I can use to pull all of their application data, and use as their identifier.

```
public function user_print( $array )
{
    if ( is_array( $array ) || is_object( $array ) )
    {
        // call back to handle function
        // cannot use $this since this is in the SONIS class scope
        $combine = applicant::handle_obj( $array );

        // set session variable to user 
        $_SESSION['user_print'] = md5 ( $combine['SOC_SEC'] . $combine['OA_PIN'] . $combine['FIRST_NAME'] . $combine['LAST_NAME'] . $combine['E_MAIL'] . $combine['APP_START_DATE'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $combine['SOC_SEC'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $combine['E_MAIL'];

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash ( 'sha512', $combine['OA_PIN'] . $user_browser );

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( $array == 'nomatch' )
        {
            $message = array(
                'is_error' => 'warning',
                'message' => 'User information is incorrect.'
            );
            return $message;
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $message = array(
                'is_error' => 'danger',
                'message' => 'We just hit a snag...'
            );
            return $message;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

To handle the response from my service I have created a unique function:

```
private function handle_obj( $array )
{
    // if it's an object we treat it as such
    if ( is_object( $array ) )
    {
        // reduce array->data to simpler format
        $call_data = array_reduce( $array->data, 'array_merge', [] );
        // combine both arrays
        $combine = array_combine ( $array->columnList, $call_data );
    }
    // if it's not an object, treat it as array.
    else if ( is_array( $array ) )
    {
        // reduce array->data to simpler format
        $call_data = array_reduce( $array['data'], 'array_merge', [] );
        // combine both arrays
        $combine = array_combine ( $call['columnList'], $call_data );
    }
    else
    {
        $combine = '';
    }

    return $combine;
}
```

I could make that code work; but I have fear of that not being the safest and really the most appropriate way to resolve this issue.

I would appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: stop using "an" before "u" words pleas thanks

Comment: There you go, @Andrew...

Comment: too kind :D !!!